# Where does AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill crop

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I'm using a `AVCaptureSession` with an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` with the `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` gravity.

```
self.captureSession =[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
self.previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.captureSession];
[self.previewLayer setVideoGravity: AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
```

How to know how the video will be resized to fit the preview area with the `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`? Which part of the image is visible in the preview area?

From [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html):

> AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill: This preserves the aspect ratio, but fills the available screen area, cropping the video when necessary

Basically, how to get exactly what was displayed in the previewLayer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [iOS 6 SDK I can use the following](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009524-CH1-SW19) in `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`

```
(CGPoint)captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:(CGPoint)pointInLayer
```